# What's the best way to report a kernel panic bug

Tags: bug-reporting, kernel

Suppose I have a machine that has no serial port and under certain reproducible situations will kernel panic. Assume I have tested the mainline kernel from the kernel team PPA and know this is an 'upstream kernel' issue.

What information should I gather to file this as a kernel bug, and where should I file it, to get it noticed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu wants us to use `apport` for reporting bugs. You will be asked a bunch of questions to provide information (so that takes part of the information you need to collect to file a bug report).

This is the [official bug reporting method](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) (page has not yet been updated to include links for Natty) with step by step how to in getting you to filing it.

There is just 1 small piece about kernel bugs:

```
For sound, X drivers, and kernel bugs: please open a new bug instead of commenting 
on a similar bug: chances are that your hardware does not match the existing bug's 
hardware, so the bug will not be addressed.
```

Good luck and please leave a comment if the answer left any questions :)

Comment: But since this is a panic, it isn't straightforward to use apport, especially if it happens right away every time I boot.  But I've heard about doing a chroot to give apport access to what it needs.  How do I do that?