# Kernel Panic on Live CD boot

Tags: kernel, live-cd

This happens pre-DM loading after booting an integrity-checked Saucy Live CD. No peripherals.

Is anyone able to suggest anything?

Photo of the output:
[image]

The TAILS live cd works fine, so I'm presuming it's not a hardware fault.

Comment: The main reason of Kernel panic is the hardware attached to your system. It would be anything like Ram, Graphics Card, HDD, CPU(heating), Sound Cards or any thing else..

Comment: @Reviewers: Don't close against "off-topic -> bug", rather http://askubuntu.com/questions/40792/whats-the-best-way-to-report-a-kernel-panic-bug ... but that assumes to be running a regular installation.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to install to an external HDD on another machine and run the installation on the external drive on the machine that gets the kernel panics. Eventually more information on the cause may land on the HDD for `apport` to pick it up and file a bug.

See: [What's the best way to report a kernel panic bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40792/whats-the-best-way-to-report-a-kernel-panic-bug)

Or the kernel panic will not appear...

Anyway good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The most probable problem in this specific case is your graphics card module (nouveau) that is causing problems. This could be either, the module is too new or too old for you graphic card. I would suggest trying an older version of Ubuntu (since you already are using the newest, then try to upgrade. Is almost sure that after the upgrade you will get Kernel Panics but in this case you will be able to use `chroot` to produce the logs apport needs.