# How to report a boot time kernel panic

Tags: kernel, crash, apport

I have a consistent kernel panic on boot, with a newer kernen that I've just installed. I still have an older kernel installed, to boot to. How can I properly report this crash to the Ubuntu kernel team, along with all of the necessary information, which probably includes the crash dump?

Comment: I did see this one:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/40792/whats-the-best-way-to-report-a-kernel-panic-bug
Mine is specifically regarding a boot time kernel panic.

Comment: If it's not an officially supported kernel version, [filing a bug on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/~canonical-kernel-team) probably does not make sense. You could instead ask on the mailing list: kernel-team[at]lists.ubuntu.com

Comment: It is an official kernel version. I've reported here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1659268

Comment: I ended up reporting using `ubuntu-bug linux-image-<...>` but that doesn't seem to add any crash dumps to the report.